# Spring CORS and Vary Headers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cors

Spring's CORS processing is automatically adding `Vary` headers to the response. In principle it makes sense.

But in my case, I don't want those headers, as the response should be public and cached in CDN independent from the `Origin` or other headers the client sends, it will always be the same response, and the allowed origins are `*`.

Reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS:

> If the server specifies a single origin (that may dynamically change based on the requesting origin as part of an allowlist) rather than the "*" wildcard, then the server should also include Origin in the Vary response header to indicate to clients that server responses will differ based on the value of the Origin request header.

Is there any reason, why Spring is adding the `Vary: Origin` header in this case?

Is there any way to disable those headers other than adding a custom filter that removes the header from the response again?

If not, I assume it will be easier to add a filter that just adds the CORS header instead of using `@CrossOrigin` and removing the other headers again.

Comment: Responding with `Vary: Origin` is indeed detrimental if the response invariably contains `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. I suspect that Spring just took the easy way out. It's [not the only way it lets its users down](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#5-validate-configuration-and-fail-fast).